# Display the umatched values

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables where 2 colomns have same values (almost). What I want is to list all the values which are not in the column of the first table.
It should be something like

```
select * from t1.column1
join t2 on t2.column1 <> t1.column1
```

How can I display these values'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below statement

```
  SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE COLUMN1 NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TAB2)
```

Comment: Thank for your quick response!